# Is there any way to list all Wi-Fi in range?

Tags: python, pyside2

I am searching for a way to list all Wi-Fi connections in my device range with QT, I want to be able to see all the Wi-Fi, not the one that the device is already connected to.

In my research I found below solution:

```
nc = QNetworkConfiguration()
ncm = QNetworkConfigurationManager()
ncm.updateConfigurations()
nc = ncm.allConfigurations()

network = None

print(len(nc))
for i in nc:
    if i.state() == QNetworkConfiguration.Discovered: # one of the flags
        print(i.name(), i.type(), " is available")
        if i.name() == "AndroidAP6002":
            print("hello wifi")
            network = I
```

With **Active** and **Defined** flags, I can't see some results corresponding to the flag, but **Undefined** and **Discovered** flags show nothing at all, is there any QT/ pyside2 way to do this and perform a connection to desired Wi-Fi?

Comment: You can use system commands to list the wifi, if it is feasible for you.
For example on a ubuntu you can do.
```
import subprocess
batcmd="nmcli dev wifi"
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
print(resutlt.decode)
```

Comment: @ultron, thanks for the comment, I know using the system commands is a way, but I did mention QT because I am looking for a  Cross-platform solution to the problem.